# Организация структуры проекта NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Нужна помощь в правильной организации структуры проекта (в основе лежит express).
Сделать планирую много чего, боюсь в дальнейшем много менять.

В проекте хочется сделать все так чтобы он легко масштабировался, была возможность "с легкостью" в него что-нибудь добавить или удалить.

Коротко о составленной мной структуре:

- _cp - содержит модели и контроллеры для админской части сайта
- app - модели и контроллеры для public части сайта
- config - общие настройки системы, какие-либо глобальные переменные...
- core - библиотеки которые используются по всему проекту (например для работы с бд или картинками)
- views - содержит темплейты страниц
- www - js,css и тд

Скриншот приаттачил для наглядности. Надеюсь на ваши советы, может кто-то имел дело с подобными задачами.

[image: Project structyre]

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то?

Answer (score 1):

Структура проекта во многом зависит от текущей ситуации, предугадать которую получается далеко не всегда. Лучше потратьте своё время на запоминание горячих клавиш рефакторинга вашей IDE